# How to call two functions on click in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have two functions inside my controller

```
$scope.first = function()
{
    console.log("first");
}

$scope.second = function()
{
console.log("hello");
}

Now in my template i give call to first function

<button ng-click="first()">click</button>
```

Now I want that as soon as my first function complete its execution, automatically my second function starts executing without any click.

That is on single click first function executes and then second function executes respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or you can do:

```
function first() {
    // Do stuff
}

function second() {
   // Do stuff
}

$scope.runBoth = function () {
    first();
    second();
}
```

The good thing with that approach is that you can listen to first() return and based on that run/skip execution of second() etc.

Also by keeping first() and second() as just javascript functions you are not adding unnecessary watchers (assuming that you're not using first() and second() somewhere else).

Comment: of corse this will run ok, but it's easier to call both function in the ng-click

Comment: It all depends on a use case.

Answer (score 10):

Just call the functions separated by `;`

```
<button ng-click="first();second()">click</button>
```